# Property 'on' does not exist on type 'FluentRules<any, any> | FluentEnsure<any> | FluentRuleCustomizer<any, any>'.

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I am writing aurelia-validation and having issue using `on` which is part of different overload (`FluentRuleCustomizer`) class. When I use `ruleBuilder['on'](field);` it works fine, but when I change that to `ruleBuilder.on(field);` I get a red squiggly line on `ruleBuilder.on(field);`. See the below code and screenshot.

```
import { ValidationRules, FluentRuleCustomizer, FluentEnsure, FluentRules } from 'aurelia-validation';
import { on } from 'cluster';
export class FormHelper {
  private static initializedForms = [];

  public static initializeFormRules(form) {
    if (this.initializedForms.indexOf(form) > -1) {
      return;
    }
    this.initializedForms.push(form);
    for (const field of form.fields) {
      if (field.validation.isValidate) {
        let ruleBuilder: | FluentRules<any, any> | FluentEnsure<any> | FluentRuleCustomizer<any, any>;
        ruleBuilder = ValidationRules
          .ensure("value")
          .displayName(field.label);

        const rules = Object.keys(field.validation.validationRule)
          .map(key => ({ key, value: field.validation.validationRule[key] }));

        for (const rule of rules) {
          ruleBuilder = ruleBuilder[rule.key](rule.value);
        }
//         ruleBuilder['on'](field);
        ruleBuilder.on(field);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/dist/commonjs/implementation/validation-rules.js) to all exported classes exposed for `aurelia-validation`

Any help is really appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: after several trial and error, I got it working. Replaced this `ruleBuilder.on(field);` with  `(ruleBuilder as FluentRuleCustomizer<any, any>).on(field);`

Comment: I think I ran in to this at some point. Sometimes TypeScript can be annoying.

Comment: Anyone know how to get around this when using `.ensure(o => o.name)`?  I was doing this in a non-Typescript project: `ValidationRules.ensure(o => o.name).required()` but now, when converting to TypeScript, I'm getting the same error as listed on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typings / api of `aurelia-validation` aren't ideal for dynamically building up rules like this, so you need to cheat a little.

Just change your initial declaration to this:

```
let ruleBuilder: FluentRuleCustomizer<any, any> = ValidationRules
      .ensure("value")
      .displayName(field.label) as any;
```

It will not actually be a `FluentRuleCustomizer` there (hence the `as any` is needed), but it will be after your logic below has applied any rules to it. Tbh I think `.displayName()` should just return a `FluentEnsure` or `FluentRuleCustomizer` (both have the `.on()` method that does the same thing) but that's another discussion.

You probably want to double check that any rules were actually applied, or the `.on()` will error out:

```
if (rules.length) {
    ruleBuilder.on(field);
}
```